# How to find the $\mathrm{P}_{\mu \nu}$ elements in the summation $\sum_{\mu=1}^K \sum_{\nu=1}^K \mathrm{P}_{\mu \nu} \Omega_{\mu \nu} = 1$

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have a Matrix $\mathrm{\mathbf{P}}$ which is real and a matrix $\mathbf{\Omega}$ which is complex. They each are square matrices $K \times K$.

Given matrix $\mathbf{\Omega}$ and knowing that the following equation holds:

$$\sum_{\mu=1}^K \sum_{\nu=1}^K \mathrm{P}_{\mu \nu} \Omega_{\mu \nu} = 1$$

Is there a way to calculate the elements of matrix $\mathrm{\mathbf{P}}$ ?

Matrix $\mathbf{P}$ has certain properties that need to be addressed when solving for it.

I) $\mathbf{P}^2 = \mathbf{P}$

II) $\mathbf{P}^\dagger = \mathbf{P}$

III) $\mathrm{Tr}[ \mathbf{P} ]= 1$

IV) $\mathrm{P}_{\mu \nu} \ge 0$